# In android how to set views of "action buttons" in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**My requirement is**:--
[image: The action bar]

and When I click the search button I want :-
[image: SEarchview]
So here is my code:--

**Snacks.java**

```
public class Snacks extends Activity {

    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_snacks);
        
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")));
                                
                getActionBar().setTitle("Snacks");
                
                getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                
                getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    
        int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView searchImg = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

        int searchDeleteImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView searchDeleteImg = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchDeleteImgId);
        searchDeleteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_delete);
        
        int searchSrcTextId = getResources().getIdentifier( "android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchSrcTextId);
        searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        searchEditText.setHint("Search Here");
        
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered Keyword is " + s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        
        return true;
    }
    
    
}
```

**activity_main_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        
          android:title="Contacts"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
     <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        
          android:title="Contacts"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>
    

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

but when I run this program I got this:--
[image: actionbar]
here,the appname **Snacks** is not showing..and when I click the searchview I got:--
[image: searchview]

This searchview expanded all over. Where Is wrong in my code That I cannot achieveing my requirement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setMaxWidth(int maxpixels) method you can use on your searchView.

```
    searchView.setMaxWidth(100);
```

Try with different sizes, not sure which will be good enough :)

Also if contacts button isn't required to be there all the time you could switch in xml for

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_contact"
android:title="Contacts"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```